# Why aren't the last numeric values of the files being read?

Tags: c, file, copy

This is a program to copy the Data from the respective files and display them. Simple. But the Code acts a bit differently...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *fptr, *fp; 
    int values[15], i, j;
    fptr = fopen("Data1.txt", "r");
    fp = fopen("Data2.txt", "r");

    if(fptr == NULL)                                //to check for error
        printf("\nError in opening Data1.txt!!\n");
    if(fp == NULL)
        printf("\nError in opening Data2.txt!!\n");

    for(i = 0; (values[i] = getw(fptr)) != EOF; i++)
        fflush(fptr);

    printf("\ni value = %d\n\n", i);

    for(; (values[i] = getw(fp)) != EOF; i++)
         fflush(fp);

    fclose(fp); //Closing both the files...
    fclose(fptr); 

    printf("\ni value = %d\nValues: \n", i);
    for(int a = 0; a <= i; a++)
        putw(values[a], stdout);

    fflush(stdout); //removing any unwanted characters

    fptr = fopen("Data3.txt", "w"); //Opening Data3.txt file
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", "The values which are present in Data1.txt and Data2.txt is as follows:\n");
    fflush(fptr);
    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if(ferror(fptr) != 0)
        {
            printf("\nSome error has occured while printing the Data into Data1.txt file!!!\n");\
            break;
        }
        putw(values[j], fptr);
        fflush(fptr);
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    
    printf("\nPlease go to the Data3.txt file to know more about the execution of the program...\nData has been recorded successfully\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The values stored in Data1.txt is

```
10 14 18 22 26 33
```

The values stored in Data2.txt is

```
1 7 14 21 28 35
```

The output of the program is like this...

```
i value = 4


i value = 7
Values: 
10 14 18 22 26 31 7 14 21 28����
Please go to the Data3.txt file to know more about the execution of the program...
Data has been recorded successfully
```

And the Data3.txt file contains

```
The values which are present in Data1.txt and Data2.txt is as follows:
10 14 18 22 26 31 7 14 21 28����
```

Why don't the last values get copied?
Moreover, the i values are 4 for the first set of Data copied and 7 for the second set of Data copied, whereas the total number of values is 12. Why does this happen?
I tried variations with a while loop and do-while loop, but nothing worked. Tried to fflush() the files after reading from them, but that too didn't work.

Comment: `fflush(fptr);` for a file being *read* has *undefined behaviour*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getw` and `putw` are not meant for text files. They're the equivalent of `fread`, `fwrite` for one `int` object from/into a *binary file*. Furthermore they're *deprecated* and exist *chiefly* to support C source code written in the previous century.

---

You want to use `fprintf` and `fscanf`.